# Character encoding problem using ScrollableResults and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, jdbc

I'm doing

```
private void doSomething(ScrollableResults scrollableResults) {
    while(scrollableResults.next()) {
       Object[] result = scrollableResults.get();
       String columnValue = (String) result[0];
    }
}
```

I tried this in two computers

1. It works fine. It is a Windows 7. System.getProperty("file.encoding") returns Cp1252.
2. When the word in the database has accents `columnValue` gets strange values. Is is a CentOS. System.getProperty("file.encoding") returns UTF-8.

Both databases are MySql, Charset: latin1, Collation: latin1_swedish_ci.

What should I do to correct this?

Comment: Can you show an example of the strange values?

Comment: @Pekka Nível gets NÃvel. With a break line after Ã.

Comment: I set file.encoding in the Windows and for Nível I get NÃ?VEL. It is different from what I get in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) everywhere:

- at the database/tables level (the following ALTER will change the character set not only for the table itself, but also for all existing textual columns)

  ```
  ALTER TABLE <some table> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
  ```
- in the connection string (which is required with MySQL's JDBC driver or it will use the client's encoding)

  ```
  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
  ```

#### References

- MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual

  - [9.1.3.2. Database Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html)
  - [9.1.3.3. Table Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html)
- Connector/J (JDBC) Reference

  - [20.3.4.4. Using Character Sets and Unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

Comment: I'd try just the JDBC connection parameters first.  You might be able to skip changing your table character encoding.

Comment: was missing character set in the alter table.